# How to get information others users in logged user (auth0.js)?

Tags: angular, auth0

I have some problem, need to get a information of all the users when I'm logged in.
Usually getting information about current user this way:

```
//...
this.authHttp.get(`https://MY_DOMAIN/api/v2/users/USER_ID`)
     .map(response => response)
     .subscribe( response => {
        //...
      },
//...
```

But when I request other user (not logged), console write this:

```
GET https://MY_DOMAIN/api/v2/users/USER_ID 403 (Forbidden)
```

and show the alert with a text:

```
"User to be acted on does not match subject in bearer token"
```

For example, user #1 need to get information about #2 (his e-mail, name), how to implement it?

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: Is this question about Auth0 or about your own backend?

Comment: about auth0.js (I'm writing on the angular2)

Comment: So in your example `https://MY_DOMAIN` is actually an Auth0 endpoint, correct? Don't you need special permission to access other user's accounts, such as admin privileges?

Comment: Yes, my_domain is correct. But I'm don't know need a permission, there is no information anywhere about getting of information accounts. In auth0.com written only about getting the data current user...